# Getting value from thread running in while loop

Tags: multithreading, java-threads

I have a java thread which is running a path-finding algorithm in a constant while loop. Then, every so often I want to retrieve the most updated path from the thread. However, I am unsure how to do this, and think I might be doing it wrong.
My thread consists of the following code:

```
public class BotThread extends Thread {

  Bot bot;
  AStar pathFinder;
  Player targetPlayer;
  public List<boolean[]> plan;

  public BotThread(Bot bot) {
    this.bot = bot;
    this.plan = new ArrayList<>();
    pathFinder = new AStar(bot, bot.getLevelHandler());
  }

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("THREAD RUNNING");
      targetPlayer = bot.targetPlayer;
      plan = pathFinder.optimise(targetPlayer);
    }
  }

  public boolean[] getNextAction() {
    return plan.remove(0);
  }

}
```

I then create an object of BotThread, and call start(). Then when I call getNextAction() on the thread, I seem to receive a null pointer. Is this because I am not able to call another method on the thread whilst it is in the main loop? How should I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not giving enough time to thread to initialise plan Arraylist. You need to add sleeping time to the threads. Something like this while calling BotThread class from main:

```
     int num_threads = 8; 
     BotThread myt[] = new BotThread[num_threads];
        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
            myt[i] = new BotThread();
            myt[i].start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            myt[i].getNextAction();

        }
```